# QTP / UFT, how to test two anti-virus applicaiton efficently

Tags: qtp, windows, hp-uft

A task is given to me to Automate some test cases on two anti-viruses s/w (McAFee and symantec)

Now the writing QTP scripts for individual is not a deal here, the actual deal here are:

1. Both the anti-virus cannot exists on a single system.
2. what could be the best approach to test both the S/w, without uninstalling and installing another s/w.

Can any one help me with an approach on how can i do this, would be very helpful.

Comment: Sounds like you'll have to have two separate machines, one for each anti-virus.

Comment: @Motti I have to write single test script to handle both anti-virus on one machines.

Comment: But you say that both Anti-Viruses can't be installed together... How would you test it if you had to test manually?

Comment: @Motti if i have to do it using two separate machines, what would you suggest to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

@Napster. You can write a single QTP script and install them on two systems having separate Anti-Viruses. Using the single QTP script you can handle both.